# Convert date time in SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datepart

I would like to find out which user are late clock in example clock in time on 9:00Am more than 9:00am declare as late but my result show me more than 10:00Am just count as late

```
DECLARE @clockin as varchar 
DECLARE @clockout as varchar
DECLARE @reportdate as datetime 

--SET @clockin = CONVERT(108,'08:30')
SET @clockin = CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST('9:00' AS TIME),100)
SET @clockout = CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST('18:30' AS TIME),100)
SET @reportdate = month(GETDATE())

SELECT
    u.showname AS showname,
    l.USERID AS USERID,
    u.BADGENUMBER AS BADGENUMBER,
    l.CHECKTIME AS CHECKTIME,
    CASE
       WHEN DATEPART(HOUR, l.CHECKTIME) <= @clockin  
          THEN CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST(l.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100)
          ELSE 'late ' + CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST(l.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) 
    END AS Time 
FROM
    CHECKINOUT l
INNER JOIN
    USERINFO u ON l.USERID = u.USERID
WHERE
    u.showname IS NOT NULL
    AND u.BADGENUMBER > 100 
    AND CHECKTIME >= '1 jan 2017' 
    AND CHECKTIME <= '31 jan 2017' 
--GROUP BY l.USERID, u.showname, u.BADGENUMBER
ORDER BY 
    u.BADGENUMBER
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare with time not just 'hour'!

```
DECLARE @clockin as TIME 
DECLARE @clockout as TIME
DECLARE @reportdate as datetime 

SET @clockin = CAST('9:00' AS TIME)
SET @clockout = CAST('18:30' AS TIME)
SET @reportdate = month(GETDATE())

SELECT 
    u.showname, l.USERID, u.BADGENUMBER, l.CHECKTIME,
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST(l.CHECKTIME AS TIME) < = @clockin  
          THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(l.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100)
          ELSE 'late ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), CAST(l.CHECKTIME AS TIME), 100) 
    END AS Time 
FROM
    CHECKINOUT l
INNER JOIN 
    USERINFO u ON l.USERID = u.USERID
WHERE 
    u.showname IS NOT NULL 
    AND u.BADGENUMBER > 100 
    AND CHECKTIME >= '1 jan 2017' 
    AND CHECKTIME <= '31 jan 2017' 
ORDER BY 
    u.BADGENUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is remove the equal sign. The person arrived at nine so they are not late because that equals the start time. You can also subract 59 seconds to the check in time so 9:00:30 am doesn't show as late. 
I would recommend using a separate field for late flag so people can use this data in other reports more easily in excel or whatever: if the person is late how much are they late by stuff like that

```
Select 
    u.showname, l.USERID, u.BADGENUMBER, l.CHECKTIME,
    case 
       when datepart(HOUR,l.CHECKTIME)  < @clockin
```